# JavaScript inside Ruby code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a question. Maybe little stupid but I want to be sure.
I know, how to hand on code from Ruby to JS and work on it. I mean js.erb file.
Simple example:

```
<% ruby_var = 15 %>
var jsVar = <%= ruby_var %>;
// jsVar => 15
```

It works.

On the same js.erb file I would like to do it reverse:

```
var jsVar = 15;
<% ruby_var = jsVar %>
```

I have no idea how I can do it. Is it possible?
Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at all and it's never needed.

**Javascript** is a client side code, that will be executed in client's browser. This code will NOT be executed on server, so you can't get anything in your ruby variable. When **JavsScript** will be executed on client side, there will be no ruby at all (all ruby scripts will be already turned into plain HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: @Damian Have you answered your question? Do you need any help how you get rid of need to save JS value into ruby variable?